# Use or together with and operators in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter using multiple items in a nested object in mongoose. The model is like this:

```
{
    name: String
    ...
    links: [{url: String, canQuery: bool}]
}
```

I'm trying to make a filter condition to do `$or` and an and operator like this:

```
name: req.params.name,
// and either
'links.url': {$ne:req.params.url},
// or
'links.url': req.params.url, 'links.canQuery': false
```

Not sure the correct way to go about it. I know there's a `$or` operator, but don't know how to use it together with ands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  name: req.params.name,
  $or: [ // and either    
    {'links.url': {$ne: req.params.url}},
    // or
    {$and: [
        'links.url': req.params.url, 
        'links.canQuery': false
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```